# why system.dattime cannot be converted to Timespan.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a `datetime` field in sql table.

From c#, I also have `datetime` type but it is supposed to store only time so I am sending it `01/01/0001 09:49:44`.

But while storing it in database it throws error:

that system.dattime cannot be converted to Timesapn.

Comment: Can you show us exact error while storing record to database

Comment: Assuming you're using SQL Server, `datetime` is the wrong data type. Use `time` instead, and then use the `TimeOfDay` property to get the time part as a `TimeSpan` (which will map to `time`). If you *must* have the date, use `datetime2` because it covers the same range as `System.DateTime`.

Comment: `TimeSpan` is a one-dimensional thing, like a line. `DateTime` is a zero-dimensional thing, like a point. If you just need to store the time of day part, you are still storing a point, there is no role of a `TimeSpan` in your case. Just send `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property which still returns a point.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `TimeOfDay` property of the `DateTime` object

```
DateTime input = DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001 09:49:44");
TimeSpan result = input.TimeOfDay;
```